# TensorFlow GPU doesn't work, How to install it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

I started learning about the tensorflow recently and decided to switch to the GPU version, because it is much faster, but I can not import it, it always gives the same error.

I already tried:

> - Installing it by pip, in python 3.6.8, cuda 10 and the most recent cuDNN for cuda 10
> - I tried reinstalling python, CUDA and cuDNN
> - Tried installing Visual Studio and installed CUDA 9 and cuDnn
> - I tried installing the latest Anaconda, created a "default" env and another in python 3.6 (also tried in 3.5), pip install tensorflow-gpu in both cases
> - my last attempt was to follow a tutorial on youtube, I did exactly as demonstrated (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZFn0dvPZUQ)

Everything i tried returned the same error.

Traceback: https://pastebin.com/KMEsZAmq

The complete code: https://pastebin.com/7tS0Rd5S (was working on CPU version)

```
    .
```

My Specs:

> - i5-8400
> - 8 GB Ram
> - GTX 1060 6GB
> - W10 home x64

Comment: Please don't use external links for tracebacks or code. We expect you to put as much code as possible *in the question* so that the question is still relevant even when the URLs die.

Answer (score 1):

just have a look here: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Tensorflow supports CUDA 9.0, you will need to downgrade your CUDA or use one of the tensorflow's docker images:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

via docker it won't use your CUDA drivers